# Python 2 Reversed Efficiency

Tags: python, performance, python-2.x, palindrome

While I imagine it may technically be implementation dependent, I'm wondering if `reversed` on Strings in Python 2 works as a generator object that just moves a pointer backward starting from the end character and doesn't do something else inefficient like first reversing the entire string in memory.  This is mostly a curiosity so that I can better understand Python!

For some context, I wrote the following `is_palindrome` function which I think is maximally efficient in terms of the total number of operations,  while not being completely unpythonic. This is assuming the above, assuming lazy evaluation, and assuming `all` short circuits.

```
  from itertools import izip, islice    
  def is_palindrome(s):
        mid_idx = len(s) // 2
        return all(f == b for f, b in izip(islice(s, 0, mid_idx), islice(reversed(s), 0, mid_idx)) )
```

Comment: `all` does short-circuit and `reversed` for a sequence is equivalent to `(sequence[i] for i in range(len(i), -1, -1))` - what exactly are you doing?

Comment: Okay, thanks, so that would be xrange for Python 2, right?  Also, not doing anything, just trying to understand the details.

Comment: Yes... you'll probably find that unless you're trying to save memory, the cost of building the generators and the gen-comp etc (starting, yielding, resuming, exiting)... will be way more than just `s == s[::-1]`

Comment: Right, makes sense.

Comment: And just to note... You can drop the 0's... A single argument to islice is considered the end...